# how to get the number of attachment and its corresponding name in an email to file scenario on Mule?

Tags: mule, counter, email-attachments

I am developing an email to file scenario where in I need the number of attachment count and its name so I can pas it to another flow. I know this can be done by MEL on the Variable component but I just cant get the values. Also, I tried to use for each but I can get the counter variable values. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count:

```
#[message.inboundAttachments.size()]
```

To get the names:

```
#[message.inboundAttachments.keySet()]
```

Comment: Thanks David! That was a big help. I am getting map values now that I can play with. I know its for another discussion but  can I access the for each counter as well so I can compare?

Comment: `inboundAttachments` implements `Map` so you should be able to do anything you're used to do on any map. For your reference: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/expression/InboundAttachmentsMap.java

Comment: Thanks again! This reference is really helpful

Comment: Hi david, Can I still use it on a for each scope? It seems that its getting lost  when I'm processing each attachment. apologies for the followup.

Comment: In theory yes, but it seems that you're hitting an issue. Please open another question with the details of the issue.